# Position from magnetometer?

Tags: magnet, magnetometer

So basically I'm trying to figure out the distance that a person's hand is from maybe a point on the center of their chest and their bicep. I'm trying to get the position they are moving in as they attempt an exercise. I've tried using accelerometer and gyros but there error is horrible and adding a magnetic sensor and then using Kalman filtering to predict the positioning is probably out of my skill level. So I'm thinking to place magnets on the bicep, wrist and center of the chest and somehow measuring the distance between them with a magnetometer as the person is moving their arm. Is this possible? If not, are there any other options I can try.

Comment: Strength of a magnetic field over distance aside (I'm sure you've held a magnet to a fridge before and see how quickly it becomes ineffective as you move it away) Why do you think trying to figure out position with a magnetic field is any simpler?

Comment: Even if you use rare earth magnets? I don't need exact positioning, I could even work with displacement from each other.

Comment: Hold a rare earth magnet up to a fridge. I mean, we have compasses that work with things as weak as the Earth's magnet field, but I don't think it's going to work the way you want it to work.

Comment: I see. That's rather unfortunate. Thank you though!

Comment: If magnetic field sensing has *any hope* of working, you'd likely need AC-field generators/sensors. And an environment free of magnetic-sensitive iron-type stuff.

Comment: Maybe stick a camera to the chest and have the glove contain some LEDs spaced apart from each other. And you can measure the distance between the lights to figure out the distance. Not obstruction proof though. Maybe a wrist band with lights all around it so obstructions are not an issue and have it be rigid so the LEDs are held at proper spacing from each other. Flexible straps won't work.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. But I think the exercises that will be performed would make the hand go out of the camera's view like behind the back

Comment: @NikB I dont think anything is going to work if that's the case.

Comment: Ouch. Thank you for the advice

Comment: Use flex sensors https://www.researchgate.net/publication/304222482_Detection_and_Tele-replication_of_Human_Hand_Motions_by_a_Robotic_Hand

Comment: I know that some animated movies used real-life dancers and actors wearing special uniforms with what looked like green or blue puff balls at key points around their body. They'd film them from a variety of angles and later post-process for a full 3D and quite realistic result. Cheap uniforms and cheap cameras, but I've no idea about getting access to the software involved. And it was post-processed. Not real-time. If you need real-time, it still may be possible and perhaps there is software out there for it. No idea. Just another thought to add to the bucket here.

Comment: Thank you @BruceAbbott

Comment: I'll check those two methods out!!

Answer (score 0):

I think capacitive proximity sensors can be made to work here.

Maybe take a look at [Theremin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theremin) operating principle.